# Extract Time Zone from String

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat

I am aware that there are several questions out there regarding this. But I have a problem with a specific date pattern. Here's an example:

```
20130401100000[-03:EST]
```

I'm having troble with the `-03` because according to the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone) documentation it should have 4 digits. The closest pattern I've got to it was this:

```
yyyyMMddHHmmss'['Z':'z']'
```

But because of the 2 digits it just won't work. Here's a code sample I'm using for tests:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String input = "20130401100000[-03:EST]";

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss'['Z':'z']'");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));    

    System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
    System.out.println(df.parse(input));
}
```

When I print the `new Date()` I get this:

```
20130528155734[+0000:GMT]
```

But when I try parsing the `input` I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20130401100000[-03:EST]"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
at Teste.main(Teste.java:17)
```

Does anyone know how I can parse the `input` into a [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) with the correct [`TimeZone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can correct the formatting with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String input = "20130401100000[-03:EST]";

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss'['Z':'z']'");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));    

    System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
    input = input.replace(":","00:");
    System.out.println(df.parse(input));
}
```

If you'll have correctly formatted dates mixed in with incorrectly formatted ones, you could use:

```
    input = input.replaceAll("(\\[[+-]\\d{2}):","$100:");
```

Comment: I like the solution with `replaceAll`, seems elegant. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

JDK 7 supports newer patterns in [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Specifically, X character adds support for ISO 8601 time zone.

Try this pattern with JDK 7

> DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss'['X':'z']'");

On JDK 7 I got the following output.

20130602140935[Z:GMT]
Mon Apr 01 13:00:00 GMT 2013